# apex tag to show all the children

Tags: html, salesforce, apex

I'm working on a visual force page to look like almost exactly as a default sales-force page, now my question is: 
is there an apex tag to bring all the children records like we have in the default salesforce page or should I implement a table from scratch. something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to implement , if its a lookup/master detail relationship that the child records have towards the parent, you can use the apex:relatedlist component. 
Go here for an example http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_relatedList.htm